# How to use crontab to launch scripts

Tags: linux, bash, script, cron

I have created a script (which I already tested if it works) and I want to use crontab to launch it everytime my pc reboots.

I created these script called **test.sh** just for fun and it's pretty easy:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
echo "HELLO WORLD!"
done
```

It just prints "Hello World" until somebody uses ctrl+c, it is located in the directory /home/myuser/Scripts.

Hence I open crontab -e and add

```
@reboot /home/myuser/Scripts/test.sh
```

I restart the machine but nothing happens, while if I manually launch the script by unsing ./test.sh it just works.

I don't know what is wrong...

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cronjob may very well be running - however you have provided no redirection of its output (stdout), so it has no where to be displayed. The tasks launched by cron are responsible for their own logging / output - cron provides no output redirection capability.

You can have the the cron job launch a terminal and then run your script in it; here is an example of that:

First setup crontab with crontab -e (running as user you want the script run as).

Add a job in the standard manner; I'm having this one run every minute for testing purposes:

```
* * * * * /home/argonauts/scripts/test.sh
```

In your script, you need to explicitly set the display and launch the terminal. Here is what I used for test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:0 xterm -hold -e bash -c "while true; do echo Hello World!; done"  &
DISPLAY=:0 konsole --noclose -e bash -c "/home/argonauts/scripts/test2.sh" &
```

The first command launches an xterm window running your Hello World loop. The `-hold` argument keeps the window open after the command is executed (which I suppose in this particular case is when true == false...).

The second command launches a konsole terminal and executes a second script inside of it. To check context I used this tiny test script `test2.sh`. `--noclose` is the equivalent to xterm's `-hold`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This is `basename $0`"
```

In 'cron' land keep in mind that there is very limited visibility to your normal shell environment. Add the command `env` to a script called by cron to see what it has access to. You will typically need to use full paths to everything, including things in /bin/. It may also default to `sh` rather than `bash`, so be explicit in qualifying the shell to be used. `sh` is typically `bash` in most distros these days, but called in a compatibility mode that can break many things.

If you are debugging a cronjob, look at /var/log/cron for details on if they are running and any errors. You should also look at the service using `systemctl status crond` to make sure it is running and not in a failed state. Lastly, journalctl and /var/log/messages contain info on the cronjobs as they execute.

And obviously change the `* * * * *` schedule in crontab to @reboot once done testing it.

There is also a very ( edit - forgot an adjective)  *similar* capability in systemd using timers. It is a bit finicky syntax wise, and by default will run as root, but in case you are curious:
https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/scheduling-tasks-with-systemd-timers.html

Answer (score 2):

How do you know that "nothing happens"? Just because the script doesn't pop up in a window on your screen, doesn't mean it is not running.

---

Cron is made for "batch" tasks, not for starting interactive programs, so not only it *won't* automagically launch a terminal window for you (though that could be done manually), most of the time it *can't* launch any graphical app as it doesn't know which X session it should use.

(In fact cron usually runs the @reboot tasks long before Xorg has initialized graphics yet...)

This means that cron jobs' output goes elsewhere – right now it's probably flooding your system log (journalctl, or /var/log/syslog, or something such) with infinitely many 'Hello World's.

Alternatively, cron can send the job output by email if the system has that configured (usually on servers). However, that only happens when the job finishes (and your example script never finishes).

---

If you want to run something that would appear on screen, there are mechanisms for doing that *on login* (not on boot):

- Chances are that you could put `~/Scripts/test.sh &` in the `~/.xprofile` file. This often works, but depends on which display manager the system uses.
- Another method is to create a `~/.config/autostart/my-test-script.desktop`:

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Name=my test script
  Type=Application
  Exec=/home/myuser/Scripts/test.sh
  Terminal=yes
  ```